# is it possible to add comma for alphanumeric while typing in the text box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to add a comma after every two alphanumeric while typing.

I saw this below code on this site. Can I replace this code with alphanumeric?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#RuleObj_Airline').keyup(function(event) {

        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            return value
                .replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to just look at last two characters and if they are alphanumeric append a comma:

```
$('#RuleObj_Airline').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    var lastTwo = $(this).val().slice(-2);
    if (lastTwo.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/g)) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya its working but one more thing if i type any special character it takes more than 2 characters after comma, so its better to avoid special characters in this case.. Thanks Yar :)